# Simple formula for triangle numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Triangular numbers are defined as Tn:=1+2+...+n for n>= 1. Find a simple formula for Tn+Tn-1 and prove it.

I know Tn=n(n+1)/2 so would Tn-1=n(n-1)/2?

And then would I prove it by just adding Tn+Tn-1?

Comment: You are doing right. One can also give a nice geometrical proof of that formula, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Relations_to_other_figurate_numbers.

Comment: After you add, you should be able to simplify the answer. A related question is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128446/why-do-consecutive-triangular-numbers-in-pairs-like-6-and-10-always-add-up-t

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that by "Tn-1" you mean "$T_{n-1}$" and not "$T_n-1$". (You could have produced this using `$T_{n-1}$`.)

I suspect that the idea isn't to use that formula and manipulate it algebraically, but to write the two sums like this:

```
  1  +  2  +  3  +...+(n-1)+ n
(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+...+  1  + 0
```

and to conclude that they add up to $n^2$.